# Use nameref for paragraphs in cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Is there a way to have `cleveref` replicate a custom reference command for paragraphs (but not for other references)?

For example, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\title{test}

\begin{document}

Current paragraph referencing with \verb|\cref|: \cref{par:paragraph}.

Desired referencing: \autoref{par:paragraph}, \nameref{par:paragraph}.

\section{My Section}\label{sec:section}
Text
\paragraph{My Paragraph}\label{par:paragraph}
Text

\end{document}
```

Produces the output:

> Current paragraph referencing with \cref: section 1.
>
> Desired referencing: section 1, My Paragraph.
>
> **1 My Section**
>
> Text
>
> **My Paragraph** Text